# 既存DLLのプロパティを隠ぺい方法

Tags: windows, vb.net

お世話になります。

VisualBasic.Netで既存のDLLコントロールの利用を考えております。
コントロールに対してプロパティグリッドでダイナミックに変更出来るようにしたいのですが編集してほしくない、見てほしくないプロパティもあり、それらを隠ぺいしたく考えています。

継承してプロパティをオーバーライドしてをつける事も考えてみました。

この時にGet Setメソッドを書かずプロパティの定義部分にをつける事で隠ぺい可能でしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

以下のように`PropertyDescriptor`を`PropertyGrid`から要求されても渡さないようにすれば表示されないようにできます。
また、プロパティへのアクセスが`PropertyDescriptor`経由であることを利用すれば、全く異なるオブジェクトのプロパティを表示させることも可能です。
これらの方法を使うことで、元のオブジェクトに手を加えること無しに表示/非表示を変更できるようになります。

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class Form1
    Sub New()

        Dim pgs As PropertyGrid() = {New PropertyGrid(), New PropertyGrid(), New PropertyGrid(), New PropertyGrid()}

        pgs(0).SelectedObject = New TestClass0()
        AddHandler pgs(0).PropertyValueChanged, Sub()
                                                    pgs(3).Refresh()
                                                End Sub

        pgs(1).SelectedObject = New TestClass1()

        pgs(2).SelectedObject = New TestClass2()

        pgs(3).SelectedObject = New Proxy(pgs(0).SelectedObject)
        AddHandler pgs(3).PropertyValueChanged, Sub()
                                                    pgs(0).Refresh()
                                                End Sub

        Dim table As New TableLayoutPanel()
        table.ColumnCount = pgs.Length
        table.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        For Each pg As PropertyGrid In pgs
            pg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            table.Controls.Add(pg)
        Next

        Me.Controls.Clear()
        Me.Controls.Add(table)
        Me.Width = 600
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TestClass0
    Public Property Hidden As Boolean

    Public Property Visible As Boolean
End Class

Public Class TestClass1
    <Browsable(False)> _
    Public Property Hidden As Boolean

    Public Property Visible As Boolean
End Class

<TypeConverter(GetType(TestClass2TypeConverter))> _
Public Class TestClass2
    Public Property Hidden As Boolean

    Public Property Visible As Boolean
End Class

Public Class TestClass2TypeConverter
    Inherits TypeConverter

    Public Overrides Function GetPropertiesSupported(context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetProperties(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, value As Object, attributes() As Attribute) As PropertyDescriptorCollection
        Dim properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value.GetType())
        Dim list As New List(Of PropertyDescriptor)
        If (properties IsNot Nothing) Then
            For Each pd As PropertyDescriptor In properties
                If (pd.Name <> "Hidden") Then
                    list.Add(pd)
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If (list.Count <> properties.Count) Then
            properties = New PropertyDescriptorCollection(list.ToArray())
        End If
        Return properties
    End Function
End Class

<TypeConverter(GetType(ProxyTypeConverter))> _
Public Class Proxy
    Sub New(ByVal source As Object)
        Me._Source = source
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Source As Object
        Get
            Return _Source
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _Source As Object
End Class

Public Class ProxyTypeConverter
    Inherits TypeConverter

    Public Overrides Function GetPropertiesSupported(context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetProperties(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, value As Object, attributes() As Attribute) As PropertyDescriptorCollection
        If (TypeOf value Is Proxy) Then
            Dim proxy As Proxy = DirectCast(value, Proxy)
            If (proxy.Source Is Nothing) Then
                Return New PropertyDescriptorCollection(New PropertyDescriptor(0) {})
            Else
                Dim properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(proxy.Source.GetType())
                Dim list As New List(Of PropertyDescriptor)
                If (properties IsNot Nothing) Then
                    For Each pd As PropertyDescriptor In properties
                        If (pd.Name <> "Hidden") Then
                            list.Add(New ProxyDescriptor(pd))
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

                If (list.Count <> properties.Count) Then
                    properties = New PropertyDescriptorCollection(list.ToArray())
                End If
                Return properties
            End If


        Else
            Return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value.GetType())
        End If

    End Function

    Class ProxyDescriptor
        Inherits PropertyDescriptor

        Sub New(ByVal original As PropertyDescriptor)
            MyBase.New(original)
            _Original = original
        End Sub

        Private _Original As PropertyDescriptor

        Public Overrides Function CanResetValue(component As Object) As Boolean
            Return _Original.CanResetValue(CType(component, Proxy).Source)
        End Function

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ComponentType As Type
            Get
                Return _Original.ComponentType
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides Function GetValue(component As Object) As Object
            Return _Original.GetValue(CType(component, Proxy).Source)
        End Function

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean
            Get
                Return _Original.IsReadOnly
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PropertyType As Type
            Get
                Return _Original.PropertyType
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides Sub ResetValue(component As Object)
            _Original.ResetValue(CType(component, Proxy).Source)
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub SetValue(component As Object, value As Object)
            _Original.SetValue(CType(component, Proxy).Source, value)
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ShouldSerializeValue(component As Object) As Boolean
            Return _Original.ShouldSerializeValue(CType(component, Proxy).Source)
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```